# Shared video is not playing

Tags: facebook, video, embed, shared, playback

I'm trying to share a video on the facebook wall // timeline.
Everything seems fine - the Debugger-Tool doesn't encounter any errors

```
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:type" content="video" />
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:url"  content="http://b2b.splaytv.de/plugins/SocialNet.ashx?videoid=5B8NwUgVj4oT5vH3ec8W_0" />
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:title" content="Speed by microsoft" />
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:description" content="(material by microsoft)" />
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:image" content="http://GDPlayGround.web.splaytv.de/Videos/5B8NwUgVj4oT5vH3ec8W_0.jpg" />
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video" content="http://b2b.splaytv.de/pl.ashx?id=5B8NwUgVj4oT5vH3ec8W_0" />
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video:width" content="420" />
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video:height" content="237" />
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:video:type" content="application/x-shockwave-flash" />
    Meta Tag:   <meta property="og:site_name" content="SPlayTV Video Platform" />
```

When sharing this video - a Thumbnail with description etc is posted on the wall. But when I try to play the video - there's only an empty box saying "download file"...

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use flash for the video to be playable in the newsfeed. At the moment, your code is pointing to the file, but it does not use a player to play the video, so the user is prompted to download the video instead.

Comment: Okay .. i found the solution ... maybe this is, what you meant

the problem was, that the link to the video was like:

http://www.domain.com/script.ashx?videoid=123456

changing this to
http://www.domain.com/script.ashx/123456

did the job